# Реферальная ссылка в Telegram, C#

Tags: c#, telegram, бот

Нужно сделать реферальную систему в Telegram Bot.
Пользователи будут переходить по ссылке, и бот должен *отреагировать* в ответ.

Как можно это реализовать? Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

Comment: Реферальная система, это передача некого уникального id пользователя в запросе (URL адресе, чат др.). Это обычный запрос HTTP или что либо подобное. То есть у пользователя спрашивает бот "Кто вас пригласил" - тот пишет его id/ник и бот обрабатывает это. Либо тоже самое по ссылке, примерно `http://site.ru/ref?id=12345`, после которой делаем какие то действия (например ищем пользователя, которому этот id принадлежит и оповещаем его). Ну а так, это довольно общий вопрос как по мне...

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне нужна ссылка телеграмма, с иными ссылками не получится это сделать.